# Drupalgap in Aegir?

Tags: multi-sites, aegir, javascript

I'm trying to use the Drupalgap module in a site created using Aegir.

Drupalgap requires I put some files in a directory called mobile-application at the base of my drupal installation. Within mobile-application is a  configuration file at http://www.example.com/mobile-application/app/settings.js where I need to specify the following path:

Drupal.settings.site_path = 'http://www.example.com';

Unfortunately as I am using Aegir's multisite setup I keep getting "Page not found". I've tried various different path settings such as;

Drupal.settings.site_path = 'http://www.example.com/sites/www.example.com';

Drupal.settings.site_path = 'var/aegir/platforms/drupal/sites/www.example.com';

I even tried creating a directory in called www.example.com.mobile-application and putting the contents of mobile-application inside it. That seemed to do something in that going to the url redirected me to http://www.example.com/install.php and resulted in this error; 403 Forbidden nginx

Anyone familiar with Aegir/multisite environments and Drupalgap?

Comment: A wild guess is that the vhost file redirects everything to index.php (as it normally should) and you may need to add an exception so that your webserver lets the request through without redirection.

Comment: Where and how do I add an exception? Should I put it into  /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/vhost.d/example.com ?

Comment: I don't remember enough details about Aegir to know the answer to that question. Since it's a separate question, the best would probably be to open a new question about that, and see if anyone can help. Your much more likely to find people who know Aegir, than people who know both Aegir and DrupalGap.

Comment: ref to your new question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/132259/stop-aegir-vhosts-redirecting-to-index-php-how-to-add-an-exception

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I use Aegir 2.x and never use the Drupalgap but I use root base files.

Create a new platform in Aegir (don't mess with the current platform) and create a new site.
After that you must have something like: `/var/aegir/platforms/platform_name/sites/new_site.com/`

If you put your files in `/var/aegir/platforms/platform_name/my_folder/my_script.js` you can access them by all sites in the platform `new_site.com/my_folder/my_script.js`

Answer (score 0):

`site_path` needs to be the root URL of the Drupal site, for example, http://www.example.com, and you need to set the path to your DrupalGap platform relative to the Drupal root, for example

```
drush @example.com vset drupalgap_sdk_dir sites/all/libraries/drupalgap-sdk
drush @example.com vset drupalgap_sdk_installed 1
```

DrupalGap does not need to be in the Drupal root.